# Wrong email dates on iPhones (imap_append)

Tags: email, date, migration, imap

I am using the PHP Imap library to copy mails from one imap server to another.
See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php

My script works fine, except the fact that there is something wrong with the mail dates.

If I connect to the new imap account in MS Outlook, the dates are correct, but if i connect to the same account with my iPhone the email dates are displayed as todays date (the date of the copy process)

So my questions is: 
How does the iPhone detect the email date from the email header, and how can I make the header correct when using imap_append?

Answer (score 1):

It may be be using the IMAP servers `INTERNALDATE` field, which is maintained by the server when the message is created on the server.

The RFC indicates, for the `APPEND` command:

```
  If a date-time is specified, the internal date SHOULD be set in
  the resulting message; otherwise, the internal date of the
  resulting message is set to the current date and time by default.
```

Do you have an interface to provide a timestamp to append?

**Edit**:

Yes, imap_headerinfo can be used:

$headerinfo = imap_headerinfo($source_imap, $message_number);
$internal_date=date('d-M-Y H:i:s O',$headerinfo->udate);

imap_append ( $imap_stream , $mailbox , $message ,  $options  , $internal_date);

I have tested your solution and it works, dates on iPhones are now correct.

Comment: It could be possible...

$internal_date is added as a parametre to imap_append from PHP version 5.3.2....

And I am using PHP version 5.3.1 :'(

Is there any change that you could verify if this causes the problems on iPhones?

Comment: I'm not able to verify it. I'm only able to tell you that if they're not using the date headers of the email, they're likely using the `INTERNALDATE`given by the server.  I don't have an IPhone.